# Objects with common property

Tags: swift

I have three different classes `A`, `B` and `C` with some commons properties. For instance all of them have property called `index`. Also all of them inheritance from other class `X` which doesn't have property `index` and I can't modify these classes (it's from framework). Now I want to create instantiation one of these classes and set `index` property. How I'm doing it now:

```
func returnPreparedObjet() -> X? {
    if some_condition1 {
        let a = A()
        a.index = 1
        return a
    }
    else if some_condition2 {
        let b = B()
        b.index = 1
        return b
    }
    else if some_condition3 {
        let c = C()
        c.index = 1
        return c
    }
    return nil
}
```

What is the best option to achieve it without repeat `.index = 1` and `return` lines? Can I achieve this also in situation when `A`,`B`,`C` don't inheritance from `X`?

Comment: maybe you can just conform A, B and C to a protocol with index variable.

Comment: Can I do it without modify A, B and C classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group the three classes under a common protocol:

```
protocol Indexed {
    var index: Int { get set }
}
```

, and add conformance for the three classes

```
extension A: Indexed {}
extension B: Indexed {}
extension C: Indexed {}
```

no code will be needed in the extensions as the classes already declare a writable `index` property.

You can then simplify the `returnPreparedObject` to something like this:

```
func returnPreparedObject() -> X? {
    let result: (X & Indexed)?
    if some_condition1 {
        result = A()
    } else if some_condition2 {
        result = B()
    } else if some_condition3 {
        result = C()
    }
    result?.index = 1
    return result
}
```